# How to hide administrator account or root in Login screen?

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, login-screen, administration, user-management

I used Ubuntu 12.04 and I want to only user account appear on the Login screen without guest and administrator account. My administrator account cannot view to everybody when their Login.

"greeter-hide-user=true" this command all account disappear. What command in user account only in Login screen?

Answer (score 1):

To hide/invisible an administrator account in login page:
    Note: replace AdminAccount with the actual administrator account e.g. admin01

```
(Ctrl + Alt + T)
login in sudoer/admin account to used this command.
    sudo usermod -u 999 AdminAccount
```

Answer (score 1):

**Easily you can change the User ID of the user you want to hide.**

The system tray only shows system users which are having USer ID =>1000

So to hide a user just give him a UID < 1000

You can change the UID using the command

```
sudo usermod -u UID username
```

**Be carfull** the numbers from 0 to 99 is reserved for system accounts, so don't use  them. Moreover you should be card in choosing the new UID not to be identical with some service users in your system.

The command:

```
awk -F':' '{ print $3}' /etc/passwd
```

will list all UID used in your system So you can choose the new UID without conflicting other user.

you can sort the list in increasing numeric to be easy to notice the UID numbers

```
awk -F':' '{ print $3}' /etc/passwd | sort -n
```

Answer (score 0):

Open /etc/lightdm/users.conf in a text editor and add the administrator user name to "hidden-users", reboot and you're done.

Comment: This doesn't work in Ubuntu 16.04.  Do you know how to do this with Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: No, I don't know. And I don't know why it wouldn't work. Are you sure LightDM is your display manager? If the output of `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` is `/usr/sbin/lightdm`, it should be and the above modification should work. If it's something else, you need the respective modification in the display manager you're using for the change to take effect.